# How to handle "the type does not fulfill the required lifetime" when using Any?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

```
use std::any::Any;

pub enum ObjectType {
    Error,
    Function,
}

pub trait Object {
    fn obj_type(&self) -> ObjectType;

    // Required to downcast a Trait to specify structure
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Function<'a> {
    params: &'a Box<Vec<Box<String>>>,
}

impl<'a> Object for Function<'a> {
    fn obj_type(&self) -> ObjectType {
        ObjectType::Function
    }

    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any { 
        self 
    }
}
```

When I try compiling the above code I get the following error. Here is the playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc827b17d2bb4ee239fc27800dbdc030) to the code

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0477]: the type `Function<'a>` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/lib.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         self 
   |         ^^^^
   |
   = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime

error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         self 
   |         ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 21:7...
  --> src/lib.rs:21:7
   |
21 | impl <'a>Object for Function<'a> {
   |       ^^
note: ...so that the type `Function<'a>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         self 
   |         ^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         self 
   |         ^^^^
   = note: expected `&(dyn Any + 'static)`
              found `&dyn Any`
```

Why is Rust compiler getting confused about the struct lifetime, since I am just returning self. Also does it want the lifetime to be 'static. It's quite frustrating learning the language.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is the `as_any` method defined in `Function`. If you look at the `Any` trait definition in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref-1), you will see that the trait has a lifetime bound of `'static`. The `params` field in `Function` has a lifetime of `'a` which won't live as long as a lifetime of `'static`. One solution is to define the `params` field as a `Box<Vec<Box<String>>>`, instead of using a reference and defining a lifetime, but without further context, it is difficult to say.

Comment: I need to store reference since the vector of strings lies in another data structure. I am working on building an interpreter in RUST and here is the [code](https://github.com/vishpat/monkey-rs/blob/stack-overflow-2021-03-14/src/object.rs) that I am trying to get working

Comment: @vishpat as this answer says, you cannot use `Any` for types with non-static lifetimes. Instead of a separate `enum`+`trait`+`any` to do your polymorphism, [store your data in the enum directly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb636c6608a9c7ae62135503e6efbbe5). See [the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) for more explanation.